# Clear kendo Validation Messages when Losing focus of the element

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-validator

I am applying kendo-Validation to a textbox and it seems to be working fine.
The problem is when I lose focus from the textbox element the validation message still remains there and I want that message to hide when the search textbox looses focus.

Here is my Html and javascript code:

```
> <div class="SearchDiv" id="Search">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "searchForm" }))
                {
                    <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" class ="txtSearch", placeholder="Search", required />  
                    <button type="submit" id="btn_submit"></button>
                }
                <script>
                    $("#searchForm").kendoValidator({
                        messages: {
                            required: "Please Enter Search Text",
                        },
                        rules: {
                            required: function (input) {
                                if (input.is("[name=searchText]") && $.trim(input.val()).length == 0)
                                    return false;
                                else
                                return true;
                            }
                        },
                        validateOnBlur: false
                    });
                 </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: you set validateOnBlur to false, it will dissapear if you click submit again and if the condition meet. Or Do you want if the searchtext is already filled then you lose focus from the search the error message to be dissapear ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have used the onblur attribute and applied a function there to hide my validation message whenever the search textbox looses focus.

```
function hideValidationMsg() {
                    $("#SearchDiv").find("span.k-tooltip-validation").hide()
                }
```

and my search box is defined as:

```
<input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" class ="form-control myGlobalSearch", placeholder="Assets search", required="required" onblur="hideValidationMsg()" />
```